# Google Play Billing Library 3.0.3 causing memory leak

Tags: android, memory-leaks, play-billing-library, google-play-billing

### According to release notes of Play Billing library 3.0.3 the memory leak has been fixed. But i am still getting this leak from Leak Canary

---

[image]

[image]

[Google Play Billing Library release notes](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/release-notes)

**Code where I am setting up the BillingClient (onCreate of my Fragment)**

---

[image]

**Code where I am calling BillingClient.endConnection() (onDestroyView of my Fragment)**

---

[image]

***Is there anything wrong with my code or is it the existing memory leak from Google's Library ?***

Comment: Having the same problem, even after updating to billing library 4.0.0 - did you find a fix or any other way to work around it?

Comment: @MàriusMoraBosch not yet 

Comment: Not fixed even yet